# Deep CNN doesn't learn and accuracy just stay in same value

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, resnet

I have a Deep CNN based on ResNet, and a dataset(10000, 50,50,1) to classify digits . when I run it to start leanrning , accuracy just stops in some value and gently occilating(around 0.2). I am wondering if it has overfitting or there is another issue involved ?

here is the identity block :

```
def identity_block(X, f, filters, stage, block):
# defining name basics
conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

# retrieve filters
F1, F2, F3 = filters

# save the shortcut
X_shortcut = X

# first component
X = Conv2D(filters=F1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', name=conv_name_base + '2a',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# second component
X = Conv2D(filters=F2, kernel_size=(f, f), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name=conv_name_base + '2b',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2b')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# third component
X = Conv2D(filters=F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', name=conv_name_base + '2c',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2c')(X)


# final component
X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
X = Activation('relu')(X)

return X
```

and convolutional block :

```
def conv_block(X, f, filters, stage, block, s=2):
conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

# Retivr filters
F1, F2, F3 = filters

# Save shortcut
X_shortcut = X

# First component
X = Conv2D(F1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(s, s), name=conv_name_base + '2a',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# Second component
X = Conv2D(F2, kernel_size=(f, f), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name=conv_name_base + '2b',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2b')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# third component
X = Conv2D(F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), name=conv_name_base + '2c', padding='valid',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2c')(X)

# short cut
X_shortcut = Conv2D(F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(s, s), name=conv_name_base + '1',
                    kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X_shortcut)
X_shortcut = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '1')(X_shortcut)

# finaly
X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
X = Activation('relu')(X)

return X
```

and finaly the ResNet:

```
def ResNet( input_shape=(50, 50, 1), classes=10):
inp = Input(shape=(50,50,1))
# zero padding
X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3), name='pad0')(inp)

# stage1
X = Conv2D(32, (5,5), name='conv1', input_shape=input_shape,
           kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name='bn1')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='pool1')(X)

# Stage 2
stage2_filtersize = 32
X = conv_block(X, 3, filters=[stage2_filtersize, stage2_filtersize, stage2_filtersize], stage=2, block='a', s=1)
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage2_filtersize,stage2_filtersize, stage2_filtersize], stage=2, block='b')
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage2_filtersize, stage2_filtersize, stage2_filtersize], stage=2, block='c')

# Stage 3
stage3_filtersize = 64
X = conv_block(X, 3, filters=[stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize], stage=3, block='a', s=1)
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize], stage=3, block='b')
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize, stage3_filtersize], stage=3, block='c')

# Stage 4
stage4_filtersize = 128
X = conv_block(X, 3, filters=[stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize], stage=4, block='a', s=1)
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize], stage=4, block='b')
X = identity_block(X, 3, [stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize, stage4_filtersize], stage=4, block='c')

# final
X = AveragePooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name='Pool0')(X)

# FC
X = Flatten(name='D0')(X)
X = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0), name='D2')(X)

# creat model

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=X)

return model
```

**update 1 :** here are the fitting and compile methods :

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

print("model compiled settings imported successfully")
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping], epochs=10)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Please include code on how the model is being trained

Comment: are the images normalized ?

Comment: Dear Matias @MatiasValdenegro. I have added model training settings in "update1".

Comment: Dear Venkata @VenkataKrishnan . No , images are not normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try **normalizing** the values of the digit image (50x50).

Then also consider how a neural network **learns** its weights. **Convolutional Neural Networks** learns by continually **adding gradient error vectors** that are **multiplied by a learning rate** computed **from backpropagation** to various weight matrices throughout the network as training examples are passed through.

The most important thing to consider is the **multiplication of the learning rate**, because once we didn't scale the training inputs the range of distributions of the feature values will be likely different from each feature, thus the learning rate would cause corrections in each dimension that would differ from one another. This is random, so the machine could be **overcompensating a correction in one weight dimension and under compensating in another**. Which is very non-ideal as this might result in an **oscillation state or a very slow training state**.

**Oscillating** means that the model is unable to **locate the center** for the better maxima in weights.
**Slow training** means moving too slow to achieve a better maxima.

This is why it is a **common practice to normalize images** before using it as an input for **Neural Network** or any **Models that is** **Gradient-Based**.

Comment: thak you for your good answer. normalizing solved my problem.:)

Answer (score 2):

- TF_Support's answer:

> Provide few samples of the dataset, loss curve, accuracy plot so we can clearly understand what you're trying to learn, it's more important than the code you provided.
>
> I would guess, you are trying to learn very hard samples, 50by50 grayscale is not much. Is your network overfitting? (We would only figure that out after looking into some plots of the validation metrics) (0.2 is it your training accuracy?)
>
> First do a sanity check on the dataset, by training a very simple CNN. I see you have 10 classes (not sure, just guessing from the function's default value), the randomized accuracy is 10%, so set a baseline first with a simple CNN and then try to improve with ResNet.
>
> Increase the learning rate and see how the accuracy fluctuates. After a few epochs, reduce the learning rate when the accuracy better than the baseline.

Comment: yes, actualy first, I started with a simple CNN and let learning rate to be chosen as default. but I didn't considered normalizing images as mentioned above. Thank you for answering :)